# How to get random data from previous methods?

Tags: ruby

I have this code:

```
name = "Jordan"

def upper(string)
  string.upcase
end

def lower(string)
  string.downcase
end

def random_name
  ["Ollie", "Ana"].sample
end

def random_case(string)
  [upper(string), lower(string)].sample
end

# Please write your code between this line...

# ... and this line

puts "My name is #{random_both()}"
```

I need to write the simplest code possible to return either

```
"`My name is ollie`" or
"`My name is OLLIE`" or 
"`My name is ANA`" or
"`My name is ana
```

I tried:

```
def random_both
  random_name + random_case
end

def random_both
  random_name.swapcase
end

random_both = random_name + random_case
```

I need to write the simplest code possible to return either

```
"`My name is ollie`" or
"`My name is OLLIE`" or
"`My name is ANA`" or
"`My name is ana`"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimal solution here *without* modifying any code is to supply the result of one as an argument to the other:

```
def random_both
  random_case(random_name)
end
```

This is one of the bedrock principles of programming: Combining method calls.

Maybe you're cover-complicating this. Ruby has dynamic method dispatch which makes this pretty trivial if you use `send` and choose the method you want to employ randomly:

```
def random_case(str)
  str.send([ :upcase, :downcase ].sample)
end
```

Then you call it like this:

```
puts "My name is #{random_case("Ollie")}"
```

Combine that with a random name:

```
puts "My name is #{random_case([ "Ollie", "Ana" ].sample)}"
```

That's a lot of Ruby code to stick into some string interpolation. There's a way to make this more concise using *variable arguments*:

```
def random_case(*list)
  list.sample.send([ :upcase, :downcase ].sample)
end
```

Where now the method accepts zero or more arguments so you can now do:

```
puts "My name is #{random_case("Ollie", "Ana")}"
```

Comment: I can't change anything that is already there. I can't only add any code between 
# Please write your code between this line...

# ... and this line 

and it has to run when I call 
puts "My name is #{random_both()}"

Comment: I've added a note at the top here.